# Battle.net keeps crashing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, 14.04, crash

I can't seem to install anything from Battle.net because every time I start up the application it crashes less than a minute after it opens. I'm using the newest Ubuntu release, and the latest Wine build. Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did it used to work?

Comment: negative, i just installed it.

Comment: File a bug with Blizzard and/or Wine, about it not working, with the crash data.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) lists "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" as a type of question that can be asked. I understand this could be considered a bug, but on a generic level a question about running a program in Wine seems like a good question. The answer is spot on as well, and helped me when I was stuck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to make sure dbghelp is disabled.

```
winecfg
```

then go to the 'libraries' tab and type 'dbghelp' in the 'New override for library:' box.  Click 'Add'.  When you do, a warning will appear, accept the warning and then 'edit' your new override to 'disabled', and then hit 'Apply'.

Comment: This worked! thank you so much, I appreciate it.