# Battle.net Won't Open

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 a few weeks ago on my system and everything was working fine. Today I went to use Battle.net and all I got was a white window followed by a generic error message. I have been trying to solve this all day. Please help!

I am using wine 1.7.38.

Comment: It is a desktop app used to install and play Blizzard games. It is an .exe file, but I had it working using wine and it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Do you use an Intel graphics adapter?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455508/battle-net-keeps-crashing-on-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue the command:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

followed by

`sudo apt-get update` and then

`sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks`

If you install wininet from winetricks it automatically adds the right settings so in the terminal, type:

`winetricks wininet allfonts`

the above command installs both wininet and several windows fonts. I'm not certain this is absolutely necessary but it shouldn't do any harm.

Finally run `winecfg` from the terminal or find “Configure Wine” in your desktop menu. Go to the “libraries” tab. You should see wininet( native,builtin) already listed there. If it isn't, put  it there

In the field labeled “New override for library” type in:
`dbghelp`
click add to put it in the list and confirm with Yes on the pop up.
click on `dbghelp (native,builtin)` that is now in the list
click edit
select disable
click “ok”

In the field labeled “New override for library” type in:
msvcp100
click add
click ok

You’re all set. [Download and install the client](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you want.

EDIT: Note that the current wine package available in the ppa may vary dependent upon the passage of time and the version of Ubuntu you are running and while this answer was confirmed with wine 1.7 at the time this answer was written your mileage may vary. You can check to see what package is currently available from the PPA for your version of Ubuntu [here.](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) For detail on recent wine tests of the Battle.net launcher on Ubuntu 16.04 see [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28855&iTestingId=93755)

Source: http://brockhatfield.com/2014/01/23/hearthstone-linux-wine/

Answer (score 0):

According to this test on [Wine HQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28855&iTestingId=87241), 14.04 does not display anything except on a black background. You need Ubuntu 14.10 for it to work. To get 14.10, run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: It seems the guy testing on 14.04 didn't really know, what he was doing. According to the [gold-rated 14.10 entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28855&iTestingId=88800) the issue lies with graphics drivers: “For intel the launcher may appear distorted or completely black without updated drivers.”

Comment: @DavidFoerster my research indicates that the issue may be with dbghelp

Comment: @DavidFoerster Maybe he didn't, but the OP might as well go to 14.10, since it's working on that for sure.

Comment: No, according to the cited entry, it doesn't work “for sure” on 14.10, if one has an Intel graphics adapter.